# Get Windows Explorer Path from Handle

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I have a question: is there a way to get the path pointed from a Windows Explorer istance of which I already have some data like HWND, process id, and a handle to the process?

I am using C++ and WINAPI / MFC in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: COM: SHDocVw.ShellWindows exposes an enumeration of Explorer (including IE) windows that includes the HWND.

Comment: Processes don't have paths. Are you looking for the path of the primary module that was used to create the process instead?

Comment: use [QueryFullProcessImageName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @IInspectable I am looking for the path explorer is currently pointing

Comment: [A big little program: Monitoring Internet Explorer and Explorer windows, part 1: Enumeration](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130610-00/?p=4133).

Comment: @AlexK. Isn't SHDocVw some C# class? I am trying this with C++

Comment: need to try the other solution but it may work, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use GetWindowThreadProcessId, OpenProcess, then GetProcessImageFileName. The documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683217(v=vs.85).aspx shows what permissions you need to request in your OpenProcess call.

Comment: This is not what I am asking for - actually doing this I get the explorer exe path; what I want is the path opened in the explorer.

Comment: Please give much more detailed information in your request. Your follow-up response is not at all obvious from your original question. You said you want to "get the path of a Windows Explorer process", which would be the explorer.exe path.

Comment: I'm sorry, should be clearer now.